# c# Order / Add Types

Tags: c#

I'am Creating a Paiement Invoice that has some info , Have The Main Categories And Subcategories , **The Main Categories can Holds some subcategories that has different prices** . And the Administrator Can add The Categories .

While Creating An Order :

```
  public void OrderAdd(Cat1,cat2,cat3)
  {
   // add Method Here 
  }
```

i don't have a Fixed or constant number of Categories it can be added and it can be deleted as well , I don't know how to do this 
 the order Method should take The Categories Always (The Client Can Only Pick Subcategories ) 
For Example :

The Customer Go the a Repair garage we give him a 5 Categories and he have to pick subcategories for all those categories

Example :

```
cat 1 => SubType 2 => Price.
cat 2 => SubType 6 => Price.
cat 3 => SubType 2 => Price.
cat 4 => SubType 4 => Price.
cat 5 => SubType 8 => Price 
Final Price => ...
```

So maybe the customer comes again after 15 days The menu has changed It has only 3 Categories now etc ...

The Main categories isn't a constant .

How can i manage to Create an Order Method for that type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, but it seems that you may want to create a delegate for Categories to which you can add individual subCategory methods each of which return a price. That way you can simply use += to add a new subcategory or -= to subtract that and the delegate Category continues to perform as expected. Again, I am not sure of your question. You may want to create a customer class the instances of which which contain a Category delegate and subcategory methods. It might be best use the IObserver/IObservable pattern to update these properties when subCategories change. This will help maintain OOP design and keep things reusable and updatable.

Comment: Hi thank you for you answer , to made it simple Lets say i have a Order method that takes 5 parameters cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4 , This Method can be changed later to take more or less parameters cause the main categories can be added and deleted

Comment: You may want to add a List<Category> as a parameter, that way you can process however many Categories you are necessary.  ex: public void OrderAdd(List<Category> currentCategories) { foreach(var category in currentCategories) category.//add method here.

Comment: To incorporate subCategories into the Categories, you could create an interface ISubCategoryList that requires each category to contain a list of subCategories and would make them accessible and updatable.